# Missing gaps in recurring series within a group

Tags: sql, t-sql

We have a table with following data

```
Id,ItemId,SeqNumber;DateTimeTrx
1,100,254,2011-12-01 09:00:00
2,100,1,2011-12-01 09:10:00
3,200,7,2011-12-02 11:00:00
4,200,5,2011-12-02 10:00:00
5,100,255,2011-12-01 09:05:00
6,200,3,2011-12-02 09:00:00
7,300,0,2011-12-03 10:00:00
8,300,255,2011-12-03 11:00:00
9,300,1,2011-12-03 10:30:00
```

Id is an identity column.
The sequence for an ItemId starts from 0 and goes till 255 and then resets to 0. All this information is stored in a table called Item. The order of sequence number is determined by the DateTimeTrx but such data can enter any time into the system. The expected output is as shown below-

```
ItemId,PrevorNext,SeqNumber,DateTimeTrx,MissingNumber
100,Previous,255,2011-12-01 09:05:00,0
100,Next,1,2011-12-01 09:10:00,0
200,Previous,3,2011-12-02 09:00:00,4
200,Next,5,2011-12-02 10:00:00,4
200,Previous,5,2011-12-02 10:00:00,6
200,Next,7,2011-12-02 11:00:00,6
300,Previous,1,2011-12-03 10:30:00,2
300,Next,255,2011-12-03 16:30:00,2
```

We need to get those rows one before and one after the missing sequence. In the above example for ItemId 300 - the record with sequence 1 has entered first (2011-12-03 10:30:00) and then 255(2011-12-03 16:30:00), hence the missing number here is 2. So 1 is previous and 255 is next and 2 is the first missing number. Coming to ItemId 100, the record with sequence 255 has entered first (2011-12-02 09:05:00) and then 1 (2011-12-02 09:10:00), hence 255 is previous and then 1, hence 0 is the first missing number.

In the above expected result, MissingNumber column is the first occuring missing number just to illustrate the example.

We will not have a case where we would have a complete series reset at one time i.e. it can be either a series rundown from 255 to 0 as in for itemid 100 or 0 to 255 as in ItemId 300. Hence we need to identify sequence missing when in ascending order (0,1,...255) or  either in descending order (254,254,0,2) etc.

How can we accomplish this in a t-sql?

Comment: Why the rows `100,Previous,255` and `100,Next,1
` in your result? There is no row missing between `SeqNumber 255` and `1`. You should have `100,Previous,1` and `100,Next,3` instead ??

Comment: They are in the result as the seqnumber for a given item resets after 255 to 0. In this case 0 is missing, hence both 255 and 1 are appearing as result. The SeqNumber 3 is for another itemid which is 200 and the missing sequence for this must be separately calculated within its set.

Comment: OK, I got it. Your result is fine. Posted a matching solution.

Comment: Please refrain from reposting your questions. Edit the original instead.

Comment: The last part is unclear to me: `or either in descending order (254,254,0,2) etc.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could work like this:

```
;WITH b AS (
   SELECT *
         ,row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ItemId, DateTimeTrx, SeqNumber) AS rn
   FROM   tbl
   ), x AS (
   SELECT
       b.Id
      ,b.ItemId    AS prev_Itm
      ,b.SeqNumber AS prev_Seq
      ,c.ItemId    AS next_Itm
      ,c.SeqNumber AS next_Seq
   FROM   b
   JOIN   b c ON c.rn = b.rn + 1                -- next row
   WHERE  c.ItemId = b.ItemId                   -- only with same ItemId
   AND    c.SeqNumber <> (b.SeqNumber + 1)%256  -- Seq cycles modulo 256
   )
SELECT Id, prev_Itm, 'Previous' AS PrevNext, prev_Seq
FROM   x
UNION  ALL
SELECT Id, next_Itm ,'Next', next_Seq
FROM   x
ORDER  BY Id, PrevNext DESC
```

Produces exactly the requested result.
See a [complete working demo on data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/120132/demo-for-vkarthik).

This solution takes **gaps in the `Id`** column into consideration, as there is no mention of a gapless sequence of Ids in the question.

---

#### Edit2: Answer to updated question:

I updated the CTE in the query above to match your latest verstion - or so I think.

Use those columns that define the sequence of rows. Add as many columns to your `ORDER BY` clause as necessary to break ties.

The explanation to your latest update is not entirely clear to me, but I *think* you only need to squeeze in `DateTimeTrx` to achieve what you want. I have `SeqNumber` in the ORDER BY additionally to break ties left by identical `DateTimeTrx`. **I edited the query above.**

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks Erwin. Just curious, from your second CTE can we not pivot/apply another cross join and get the result? Frankly I don't know if this doable but just saying. I have actually few more columns that I will get from some other tables and am just wondering any effect of UNION ALL.

Comment: @VKarthik: UNION ALL is safe. Pivot is certainly possible. Cross join with a table variable holding two rows for `PrevNext` and use CASE statement is possible, too. But I think the solution presented is faster and simpler. One tiny change: JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN - LEFT is not needed & without effect in this case.

Comment: Erwin, I came across a problem now. Actually the records that we get are not exactly in sequence and the gap between the two sequence numbers may be more than one. The query posted is failing in such cases. I have tried changing the ordering clause but its not getting filtered. Could you let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: @VKarthik: Your description is not clear. "Records not in sequence", "gap may be more than one", .. these statements are not conclusive. Gaps in the primary key column `Id` are without effect to my query as long as the IDs are strictly in ascending order. I would suggest you edit your question or post a new question with all the necessary data to make your case clear.

Comment: I have now modified the input data. What I was saying was the order of the sequence number for an item is not exactly in order and when i execute that it is ignoring the previous missed sequence. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well I did try ordering but the problem here being the sequence should show 254 as Previous and then 1 as Next. With a normal ordering it shows 1 as Previous and 254 as Next.

Comment: @VKarthik: As this kind of ordering is circular, it cannot be solved without additional information.

Comment: Well actually that is what I have tried to explain. On a given set of time interval , the reset can happen only once i.e. sequence will never occur twice. Secondly, the sequence will always reset in an descending fashion i.e. in this case 255,0,1. Please let me know if you need more information or what the additional information is?

Comment: @VKarthik: What time interval? And `255,0,1` .. descending fashion? You lost me. If you can define where `SeqNumber` starts, you can solve the problem. You best edit the question or start a new one with all the information that is not in this one.

Comment: @Erwin..I have now edited the question.Hope this is clear now.

Comment: Thanks yet again. sorry for the late reply. I understand now that ordering is what differentiates and sets them apart.