# Gaps in recurring series of a group with datetime

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Missing gaps in recurring series within a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360901/missing-gaps-in-recurring-series-within-a-group)

We have a table with following data

```
Id,ItemId,SeqNumber;DateTimeTrx
1,100,254,2011-12-01 09:00:00
2,100,1,2011-12-01 09:10:00
3,200,7,2011-12-02 11:00:00
4,200,5,2011-12-02 10:00:00
5,100,255,2011-12-01 09:05:00
6,200,3,2011-12-02 09:00:00
7,300,0,2011-12-03 10:00:00
8,300,255,2011-12-03 11:00:00
9,300,1,2011-12-03 10:30:00
```

Id is an identity column.
The sequence for an ItemId starts from 0 and goes till 255 and then resets to 0. All this information is stored in a table called Item. The order of sequence number is determined by the DateTimeTrx but such data can enter any time into the system. The expected output is as shown below-

```
ItemId,PrevorNext,SeqNumber,DateTimeTrx,MissingNumber
100,Previous,255,2011-12-01 09:05:00,0
100,Next,1,2011-12-01 09:10:00,0
200,Previous,3,2011-12-02 09:00:00,4
200,Next,5,2011-12-02 10:00:00,4
200,Previous,5,2011-12-02 10:00:00,6
200,Next,7,2011-12-02 11:00:00,6
300,Previous,1,2011-12-03 10:30:00,2
300,Next,255,2011-12-03 16:30:00,2
```

We need to get those rows one before and one after the missing sequence. In the above example for ItemId 300 - the record with sequence 1 has entered first (2011-12-03 10:30:00) and then 255(2011-12-03 16:30:00), hence the missing number here is 2. So 1 is previous and 255 is next and 2 is the first missing number. Coming to ItemId 100, the record with sequence 255 has entered first (2011-12-02 09:05:00) and then 1 (2011-12-02 09:10:00), hence 255 is previous and then 1, hence 0 is the first missing number.

In the above expected result, MissingNumber column is the first occuring missing number just to illustrate the example.

We will not have a case where we would have a complete series reset at one time i.e. it can be either a series rundown from 255 to 0 as in for itemid 100 or 0 to 255 as in ItemId 300. Hence we need to identify sequence missing when in ascending order (0,1,...255) or  either in descending order (254,254,0,2) etc.

How can we accomplish this in a t-sql?